# Center align dropdown menu in each nav item

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with a specific size, 800px wide and 50px tall, inside I have an unordered list of 6 elements, aligned to center of this `div`, everything works fine so far.

Then I want to create a dropdown list from each element. Right now I have the second `ul` aligned to the left side of the container `div`.

I'm trying to keep it aligned to center of each element, and the `ul` elements can't be the same width. Here is what I have so far: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tjr1nb5/8/). Any suggestions?

```css
#bar {
  width: 800px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
.test-navbar ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: ;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.test-navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.test-navbar a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 9px;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #313131;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 23px;
  background-color: ;
}
.test-navbar a:hover {
  color: #f50057;
}
.test-navbar ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.test-navbar ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: ;
}
.test-navbar ul ul a {
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: ;
}
.test-navbar ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <div class="test-navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">PASION</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION5</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">EXTRA AREA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">VIDEO</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ANOTHER LINK</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION5</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXTRA FROM PASION6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">LINK5 STYLE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BYE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relative + absolute positions, with transform tricks.

```
.test-navbar li {
  position: relative;
}
.test-navbar ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tjr1nb5/9/)**

Comment: Thanks @Pangloss it works! I'll be studying what you did to understand it better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question, but I believe you are trying to achieve the following effect: http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/dropdown-with-html-css-demo/

To do that you can follow this tutorial: http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-dropdown-menu-with-html-css

Here is a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8apu5yp6/

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Movies <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">T.V. Shows</a></li>
            <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Site Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background:#bf5c71 url('body-bg.jpg');
}

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#919191;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#be5b70;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#2e2728;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#2e2728;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#3e3436;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D alright, I included the html css that shows to do that along with a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* NAV BAR */

.test-navbar {
    background-color: #333; 
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
} 

.test-navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.test-navbar ul li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #dede0e;
    font-size: 1.5em;

}
.test-navbar ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 10px;

}
.test-navbar ul li:hover {
    background-color: #000000;

}

/* DROP DOWN MENU */

.test-navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: blueviolet;
    background: #a80000;
    position: absolute;

}
.test-navbar ul ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border-top:3px solid white;
}
.test-navbar ul ul li a {
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.test-navbar ul li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}
```

Try This

It was from a my demo nevbar